Prove that value of given polynomial can't be negative $2x^2 +5y^2 +3z^2 -6xy -2xz + 5yz$
Obviously, I tried transforming polynomial into a sum of squares.
Nothing worked, there are simply not enough squared variables to match the product of them to make a square.
$(x^2 -4xy +4y^2) + (x^2 -2xy + y^2)$ uses all xs and ys just for $-6xy$,we also have $-2xz$ and $5yz$.I suppose that there may be a trick to combine parts of $-6xy,-2xz,5yz$ and then make a square.
I don't know what to do,I have done so many polynomial problems but have never encountered something like this.On first glance, I would think that it may not always be positive.
What is approach to solving this kind of problems,I just can't see the combination.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the related Any $(x, y, z)$ can satisfy the $5x^2+2y^2+6z^2-6xy-2xz+2yz<0$?.

$x,y,z$ can all be positive or negative (or zero, but that is irrelevant since we don't need to show the polynomial is positive, only that it is not negative). From this point you could basically brute-force the result by showing all options lead to a positive sum.

I understand,good point,still I want to transform into sum of squares

Thank you,I learned more on this site then with all private classes with my math professors

@Red, I don't think it's that easy. A small change in one of the coefficients could shift this form to one taking on negative values. E.g., if we changed $-6xy$ to $-6.4xy$ the polynomial would no longer always be positive. It's value at $(1.6,1,0)$ would be $-0.12$.

Not those coefficients, only the $x^2,y^2,z^2$ coefficients and I'm only thinking about splitting them as in writing $3y^2$ as $2y^2+y^2$ to see if something drops out nicely. No luck so far.

@Red, if you change the $2x^2$ to $1.7x^2$, or the $5y^2$ to $4.4y^2$, the resulting polynomial takes on negative values.

Solution from my book if it helps:$1/2(2x-3y-z)^2 +1/2(y+2z)^2 +1/2z^2>=0$

That's the result in Will Jagy's answer, Steph.

You are right,it is

@GerryMyerson, I realise this. I clearly did not explain my idea well enough and it doesn't matter now anyway as others have posted much better answers. Thanks though.

If you don't want to use matrices: Let $-k$ be any negative number. You need to show that the following has no solutions $(x,y,z)$:
$$2x^2 +5y^2 +3z^2 -6xy -2xz + 5yz = -k $$
We rewrite this as
$$2x^2 - (6y + 2z) x + 5y^2 + 5yz + 3z^2 + k = 0$$
We now use the quadratic formula and solve this for $x$, obtaining
$$x = \frac{3y + z}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ -y^2 - 4yz - 5z^2 - 2k}}{2}$$
But the expression under the square root sign is $-(y + 2z)^2 - z^2 - 2k$, which is always negative. Hence the roots will never be real.
We conclude the polynomial in question is never negative.

The corresponding symmetric matrix is
$$
\pmatrix{2&-3&-1\cr-3&5&5/2\cr-1&5/2&3\cr}
$$
The principal minors of this matrix are all positive, so the matrix is positive definite, so the original form is positive definite.

Thank you a lot for help.Unfortunately,matrix method is unknown to me.Can you please give me resource where should I check this concept out.

Any Linear Algebra text (or webpage) will tell you how to multiply matrices. If $v$ is a vector of variables and $A$ is a square matrix then $v^tAv$ is a quadratic form in the variables ($v^t$ means the transpose of $v$). Any good discussion of positive definite matrices should explain the principal minors result. "Positive definite" would be a good search term, also "principal minor".

Thank you,I will research this concept.It isnt coverd in polynomial part of linear algebra classes in my high school right now,but we will do matrices in several weeks on geometry classes

If there are no matrices in your linear algebra classes, then they aren't linear algebra classes.

As Will writes, it's repeated completing the square. Without using any matrix notation, it can be done explicitly as follows:
First, you won't mind if I multiply by two, to get a square coefficient on the $x^2$ term, so
$$
W=4x^2+10y^2+6z^2-12xy-4xz+10yz
$$
Now, let's just look at the terms containing $x$, and do completing the square:
$$
4x^2-12xy-4xz=(2x-3y-z)^2-9y^2-6yz-z^2
$$
so
$$
W=(2x-3y-z)^2+y^2+4yz+5z^2
$$
Now for the $y$ terms we do
$$
y^2+4yz=(y+2z)^2-4z^2
$$
so
$$
W=(2x-3y-z)^2+(y+2z)^2+z^2
$$
and we're done.

This approach is the most elegant one of all suggested here.

This is repeated completing the square, while the outcome comes from Sylvester's Law of Inertia. The diagonal matrix $D$  has three positive elements on the diagonal, so all three eigenvalues of $H$  are positive.
For those who have trouble completing squares, there is a method discussed at reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 6 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 6 & 10 & 5 \\ 
 - 2 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 6 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 6 & 10 & 5 \\ 
 - 2 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
The second version says that
$$ (2x-3y-z)^2 + (y + 2z)^2  + z^2 $$
is a multiple of your form, that is
$$ (2x-3y-z)^2 + (y + 2z)^2  + z^2 = 2 \left( 2x^2 +5y^2 +3z^2 -6xy -2xz + 5yz\right) $$
